# PHP - Code works on localhost, but not on a live site

Tags: php, localhost, web-hosting

Ok, here is the problem. This code works on localhost, but not on a live site

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size = 30;
$image_width  = 120;
$image_height = 40;
$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$line_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

for($x=1; $x<=30; $x++){
  $x1 = rand(1, 100);
  $y1 = rand(1, 100);
  $x2 = rand(1, 100);
  $y2 = rand(1, 100);
  imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $line_color);
}

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font2.ttf', $text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

The localhost and the webhosting are both running the same php version

**Take a look at this picture before you post anything, please!:**

http://s2.postimg.org/etamdsk95/help_me.png

Comment: Problem with php extensions ;)

Comment: post the contents of your php.ini

Comment: Has the remote server got GD extension installed and enabled?

Comment: GD: http://s8.postimg.org/uxsy67179/image.png

Answer (score 0):

try to look at error.log (APACHE), it could also be 
possible that there is a session problem, you could
try to hide all errors by using "error_reporting(0);

try this:

```
<?php
@session_start();
error_reporting(0);
@header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size = 30;

$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;

$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$line_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

for ($x=1; $x<=30; $x++) {
$x1 = rand(1, 100);
$y1 = rand(1, 100);
$x2 = rand(1, 100);
$y2 = rand(1, 100);

imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $line_color);
}

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font2.ttf', $text);
imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

but the best, would be to fix the error, so look @ the error.log

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

if you got any error message, you could tell us - so we will try to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

there are some error at your code, but it's not the PHPGD lib error, please notice code below:

```
<?php
//session_start();
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
//$_SESSION['secure']; disabled, this will lead to notice: undefined index
$text = "he123"; 
$font_size = 30;
$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;

$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); //add background color
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0); //red for the text
$line_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,255,0); // green for the line

for($x=1; $x<=30; $x++) {
    $x1 = rand(1, 100);
    $y1 = rand(1, 100);
    $x2 = rand(1, 100);
    $y2 = rand(1, 100);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $line_color);
}

// add ./ to the font name
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, "./font2.ttf", $text);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image); // remember to clear the chace :p
?>
```

here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsCpq.jpg)